# How to display a message in javascript pop up boxes

Tags: javascript, html, alert

In y project i'm using this library to display pop up boxes http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

to be precise i am using the alert directive to display pop up messages. My question is that is there a way i can pass html text into the java script function to display a message?

for example

in my file i have got something like:

```
> <p>  I want this to be displayed as a message in the alertify pop up
> message box </p>
```

Display Message

```
<script> 
    function message() {
        alertify.alert(/**this is where i would like to pass the message from  html 
        to be displayed but how would i do this?**/); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need set id to `<p>`:
`<p id='text'>  I want this to be displayed as a message in the alertify pop up
message box </p>`

and get it using javascript:
`alertify.alert(document.getElementById("text").innerHTML)`

Comment: Hi .. whats the best way to achieve this in a div? instead of a paragraph?

Comment: Hi, div is the best way, you can organize your messages in such way and put them to separated file: <div id='text1'>text1</div>,  <div id='text2'>text2</div>. And call what ever you want by ID.

Answer (score 0):

For Alertify message I use this :

```
window.showAlert = function(){
    alertify.alert('<a href="javascript:showConfirm();">Show Confirm</a>');
}

window.showConfirm = function(){
    alertify.confirm('<a href="javascript:showAlert();">Show Alert</a>');
}
//works with modeless too
alertify.alert().setting('modal', false);
alertify.confirm().setting('modal', false);

window.showAlert();
```

You can take a look [here](http://alertifyjs.com/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add some id to text container:

```
 <p id='text1'>  I want this to be displayed as a message in the alertify pop up message box </p>
```

Then:

```
function message( text ) { alertify.alert( text ); }

message( $('#text1').text() );
```